# Retrieve data from a listview

Tags: c#, listview, windows-store-apps, itemsource

In my Windows store app there is a list view which is using an item source to get data. It looks like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="lsvLinks" IsItemClickEnabled="True" 
          SelectionMode="Single" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs2}}" ItemClick="lsvLinks_ItemClick" >
   <ListView.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <WrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalChildrenAlignment="left"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemsPanel>
   <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
         <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
         <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-7.5"/>
      </Style>
   </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="340" Height="32" Background="#FFBE9CDE" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <StackPanel Width="255" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="15,0,0,0">
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Link}" Foreground="{Binding Color}" FontSize="15" Margin="0,3,0,0" FontWeight="Normal"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Width="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0">
               <Button x:Name="btnRemove" Width="30" Height="30" Margin="20,0,0,0" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Remove" Click="btnRemove_click">
                  <Button.Template>
                     <ControlTemplate>
                        <Image Source="Assets/cancel.png" Width="30" Height="30"/>
                     </ControlTemplate>
                  </Button.Template>
               </Button>
            </StackPanel>
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

My C# code

```
try {
    IEnumerable < linkTable > obsCollection = (IEnumerable < linkTable > ) await webservice.getLinksStudentAsync(1);
    linkList = new List < linkTable > (obsCollection);

    int count = 1;
    foreach(linkTable linkL in linkList) {

        if (linkL.status.Equals("yes")) {
            links.Add(new Collection {
                ID = count, Link = linkL.link, Type = "Accept", Color = "green", BackColor = "#FFA27BC7"
            });
        } else if (linkL.status.Equals("no")) {
            links.Add(new Collection {
                ID = count, Link = linkL.link, Type = "Reject", Color = "Red", BackColor = "#FFA27BC7"
            });
        } else {
            links.Add(new Collection {
                ID = count, Link = linkL.link, Type = "Pending", Color = "White", BackColor = "#FFA27BC7"
            });
        }

        count++;

    }

    cvs2.Source = links;
}
```

When a user selects an item in the listview, I need to retrieve its ID. But I don't understand how to do that. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add a `SelectionChanged` event to the `ListView` and implement it.

```
public void ItemSelected(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var item= lsvLinks.SelectedItem as Collection;
    int ID = item.ID;
}
```

On your ListView you could add the event as below.

```
<ListView x:Name="lsvLinks" IsItemClickEnabled="True" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs2}}" SelectionChanged="ItemSelected" >
```